# Matlab code for fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to write in Matlab a function that appreciates the fixed point iteration for a system of equations. The idea is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
x{_{1}}^{m+1}\\ 
x{_{2}}^{m+1}
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}y{_{1}}^{n}+hf{_{1}}(x{_{1}},x{_{2}})\\ y{_{2}}^{n}+hf{_{2}}(x{_{1}},x{_{2}})
\end{bmatrix}$

The iterations stop when $ |x_{1}^{m+1} -x_{1}^{m}|<TOL$ and $ |x_{2}^{m+1} -x_{2}^{m}|<TOL$ or when m arrives the limit of iterations M...

At the function, do I have to write :
 if ($|x_{1}^{m+1} -x_{1}^{m}|<TOL$ && $|x_{2}^{m+1} -x_{2}^{m}|<TOL $){
            $y_{1}=x_{1}^{m+1}$;
            $y_{2}=x_{2}^{m+1}$;
}
? But when only one of them is smaller than TOL how can it get its value ??

Comment: If only one of them is smaller than TOL, the iteration goes on.

Comment: So is my "if" loop right, or should it be OR instead of AND ???

Comment: Based on your description, definitely you should use `&&`.

Comment: Could you take a look at my "for" loop?? Is this right??
[code]for m=1:M
        $x_{1}$(m+1)=y1n+h*$f_{1}$($tn+h,x_{1}(m),x-{2}(m)$);
        $x_{2}$(m+1)=y2n+h*$f_{2}$($tn+h,x_{1}(m),x_{2}(m)$);
        if (abs($x_{1}(m+1)-x_{1}(m))<TOL$ && abs($x_{2}(m+1)-x_{2}(m))<TOL$)
            $y_{1}=x_{1}(m+1)$;
            $y_{2}=x_{2}(m+1)$;
            return
        end
        x1(m)=x1(m+1);
        x2(m)=x2(m+1);
    end
    $y_{1}=x1(M)$;
    $y_{2}=x2(M)$;[/code]

Comment: Looks ok, but if you literally write `y_{1}` and put it in MATLAB, I believe MATLAB will give you a syntax error.

Comment: I want to use this function for the Backward Euler Method for 2x2 systems... For example: $\begin{bmatrix}
y{_{1}(t)}\\ 
y{_{2}(t)}
\end{bmatrix}'= \begin{bmatrix}-y{_{2}(t)}\\ y{_{1}}(t)
\end{bmatrix}$, $y_{1}(0)=0$, $y_{2}(0)=1$... I wrote it by hand, and the results are not the same with of the Matlab code...

At the Backward Euler Code, I wrote:
for n=1:N 
       [Y1,Y2]=stage(y1(n),y2(n),h,t(n));
       t(n+1)=t(n)+h;
       y1(n+1)=y1(n)+h*S(t(n+1),Y1,Y2);
       y2(n+1)=y2(n)+h*G(t(n+1),Y1,Y2); 
    end

(stage() is the function of the fixed point iteration)
What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Do you have to write the code by hand? for there is something like `ode45`...you know...Actual coding is never ever never ever done by hand first, pseudo-code and structure maybe, but you have to test your code line by line by choosing appropriate testing cases.

Comment: I have to implement the Backward Euler Method for the system above using the fixed point iteration... Now I checked the results with ode45, and they are wrong... I think that I did a mistake either at the function that appreciates the fixed point or at the BackwardEuler function at the line where I'mcalling the function stage... But I do not know what exactly my mistake is... :/